# Переменной «result» присваивается значение "Good" если «check» == true и "Bad",если «check» == false.Что не так в коде?

Tags: javascript

```
var check = true;
var result;
if (check == true) {
    var result = "Good"
} else {
    var result = "Bad"
}
```

Comment: откуда предположение, что что-то не так?

Comment: Первым делом - отсутствуют закрывающие точки с запятой в операторах внутри IF. Явно - не так...

Comment: @Akina, это допустимо, js сам расставляет недостающие на его взгляд точки с запятой. Это не является ошибкой.

Comment: оффтоп конечно, но `if(check == true)` уместнее писать просто `if(check)`. А для подобных конструкций как в коде, вообще лучше использоват тернарный оператор: `var result = check ? "good" : "bad";`;

Comment: @teran, все зависит от проверяемых значений: если `check` равен `2` - то в `check == true` вернет `false`, а `if(check)` рассмотрит как `true`

Comment: @Grundy думаю, это всем известный факт. Однако, автор в своем коде использует булевы значения для `check`. Относительно этих данных я и написал комментарий.

Comment: `var result, result, result;` Что не так в коде? Да ок всё.

Comment: @vp_arth, даже приведенный в комментарии код не ошибочен и не кидает никакую ошибку. В вопросе же, можно даже притянуть за уши логическое обоснование использования `var` внутри ветки. И код все еще остается рабочим.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Для однозначности можно переписать так:
    var check = true; 
    var result; 
    if(check){ 
      result="Good" 
    } else{ 
      result="Bad" 
    }

Comment: почему должно быть так?

Comment: _Если внутри блока используется ключевое слово "var", то в нем создается новая переменная, которая при выходе из блока удаляется._ - ошибочное утверждение

Comment: если переменная создается внутри блока - это локальная переменная. если переменная создается вне блока - это уже глобальная переменная

Comment: Здесь речь идет о javascript. У него переменные объявленные с помощью ключевого слова `var` имеет область видимости ограниченную _текущей **функцией**_, а не блоком (`{`,`}`). Утверждение было бы справедливо для `let` либо `const`, но в данном случае про них речи нет. Данный ответ полностью ошибочен

Answer (score -3):

В **JS** не задается область видимости, как следствие нет необходимости использовать **var** внутри **if**, в результате синтаксическая ошибка =)

Comment: А где тут синтаксическая ошибка? код отлично выполняется

Comment: @Grundy в JS же есть правило что нельзя объявлять переменную внутри if

Comment: @YevgenyIgnatyev где вы про такое прочитали?

Comment: Это вопрос стиля, `jslint`/`jshint` ругаются, да. Однако, для js тут всё ок.

Comment: [ссылка](https://fiddle.jshell.net/sswaL3kk/) - почему же тогда данная конструкция не работает ?

Comment: Потому что синтаксис **условия** if не предполагает объявления var

Comment: @YevgenyIgnatyev, очевидно потому, что это **ошибка синтаксиса**.

Comment: @YevgenyIgnatyev это шутка? Хоть в одном примере есть такой код, где var засовывают под условие? Вы совсем не поняли вопроса. Такое ощущение что вы сами придумали проблему не прочитав внимательно вопрос, и сами на него пытаетесь ответить

Comment: @Grundy Ну так, а Вы мне говорили что "Где тут синтаксическая ошибка?"

Comment: @YevgenyIgnatyev в примере нет синтаксической ошибки, а у вас есть

Comment: "А где [тут](https://fiddle.jshell.net/sswaL3kk/1/) синтаксическая ошибка?  код отлично выполняется"

Comment: @YevgenyIgnatyev, но мы же рассматривали пример кода из вопроса. Или какой пример кода? :-) В коде в вопросе все ок - он отрабатывает именно так как и задумывалось, по окончанию переменные имеют ровно те значения, которые и ожидались. Не вижу там попытки объявления переменной как в указанном фиддле